# Why does this code cause the div to disappear?

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, toggle

I've searched for the past couple hours to figure out why this causes the div to disappear. I am trying to get the background color to toggle on click. Basically I want the background to be darker when selected, indicating it is selected. Then after being clicked again go back to it's norm.

I am using jQuery 3.3.1

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj1m9482/)

HTML

```
<div id="readMailFunctionCellReply"><img src="images/reply.png" title="Reply" /><br>Reply</div>
```

CSS

```
#readMailFunctionCellReply{
justify-content: center;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:5px;
text-align: center;
/* border: 1px solid #a45127; */
color:#a45127;
}
#readMailFunctionCellReply:hover{
cursor:pointer;
background-color: #ffedc5;
text-decoration: underline;
color:#a45127;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '#readMailFunctionCellReply', function() {

   $("#readMailFunctionCellReply").toggle(
      function() { 
         $("#readMailFunctionCellReply").css("background-color:#ffedc5");
      },
      function() {
         $("#readMailFunctionCellReply").css("background-color:");
      }
   );
})
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your need, I have the following code for you.

```js
$("#readMailFunctionCellReply").click(function(){
   $("#readMailFunctionCellReply").toggleClass("orangeBG");
});
```

```css
#readMailFunctionCellReply{
 justify-content: center;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 text-align: center;
 /* border: 1px solid #a45127; */
 color:#a45127;
}
#readMailFunctionCellReply:hover{
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color: #ffedc5;
 text-decoration: underline;
 color:#a45127;
}
.orangeBG {
  background-color: #ffedc5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="readMailFunctionCellReply"><img src="images/reply.png" title="Reply" /><br>Reply</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, I didn't think to add a class for the purpose. Thank you.

Comment: It might be helpful to mention what you've changed; what was the problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: @showdev So what I did was add the class `.orangeBG` to the CSS and I trimmed the Java to what @Sam had listed in his response. I make it a point to not call external sources so I already call a copy of jquery-3.3.1.min.js locally.

Comment: I am glad the code works for you @Sabyre and I will be giving more description for the answer moving forward. The ultimate goal was to make the code functional to the way you wanted it and keep it as clean as possible. So I used toggleClass() instead.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is not [.toggle](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp) but [.toggleClass](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp). The first actually toggles the element itself, hiding and showing it. Toggleclass on the other hand does what it says on the tin, it pops a css class in and out of the element.
All you need is to implement the matching CSS class.

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '#readMailFunctionCellReply', function() {
    $("#readMailFunctionCellReply").toggleClass("selected"); 
});
```

CSS:

```
#readMailFunctionCellReply.selected{
    background-color: pink;
}
```

JsFiddle, using pink for added pizzaz:
https://jsfiddle.net/6kswc9ug/

Answer (score 1):

Use toggleClass() instead of toggle() (and add a class into your css) :

CSS :

```
 #readMailFunctionCellReply{
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  text-align: center;
  /* border: 1px solid #a45127; */
  color:#a45127;
}
#readMailFunctionCellReply.selected{
  background-color:#ffedc5;
}
#readMailFunctionCellReply:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color: #ffedc5;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color:#a45127;
}
```

JS :

```
$(document).on('click', '#readMailFunctionCellReply', function() {

    $("#readMailFunctionCellReply").toggleClass("selected");

})
```

or for the JS :

```
$('#readMailFunctionCellReply').click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("selected");

})
```

The toggle() function change the display property (display or hide the matched elements). Check [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the:

```
 $("#readMailFunctionCellReply").toggle(function()
```

the toggle function toggles visibility of the item, rather you need to use addClass or toggleClass.

I have a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Preston17/vo4kaj6d/